# ActiveRecord: Query where column NOT in array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

ActiveRecord has a very neat syntax for querying records where a column is equal to any value in a given array:

For a simple example, let's say you have 10 products with ids 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

```
Product.where(id: [2,3,4,5,6])
```

will return products 2,3,4,5 and 6.

Is there an ActiveRecord equivalent for querying products where the column does **not** equal any value in an array?

Something like:

```
Product.where('id != ?', [2,3,4,5,6])
```

except that it actually works...

And when you pass it `[2,3,4,5,6]` in this case, it will return products 1,7,8,9 and 10.

**EDIT**

I need a Rails 3 solution!!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can negate any where clause with [`where.not`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions) in Rails 4:

```
Product.where.not(id: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

In Rails 3 you can leverage ARel:

```
Product.where(Product.arel_table[:id].not_in([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

The generated SQL in both cases is

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" NOT IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Comment: That is introduced in Rails 4 right? I am still (reluctantly) using Rails 3! Can you tell me what SQL this query generates?

Comment: You can see what sql is generated by calling `to_sql` on an ActiveRecord relation object. See my edit.

Answer (score 7):

Use following for rails 3

```
Product.where('id NOT IN (?)', [2,3,4,5,6])
```